# "go at it with everything you've got" vs "go for it with everything you've got"

Tags: prepositions

From the dictionary, I understand that *go at* means “undertake” and “tackle”, while *go for* means “go after with maximum efforts”.

I feel that the latter above is redundant, because *go for* already implies “with everything you’ve got”. As such, we should use the former one.
Am I right?

Comment: It's the difference between going at something (attacking it) and going for something (trying to get it).

Comment: @Drew  And that's different how? go at is stronger than go for? go at has another meaning than "attack". I think it's the other meaning here.

Comment: You are wrong to believe that redundancy is bad.

Answer (score 0):

**Go** can take many prepositions.

**To go for** something, as Drew's comment says, means to try to *obtain* or *achieve* something.

**To go at** something, as Drew's comment says, is to use a great deal of force to *perform an action* (which is the sense of "attacking" in Drew's comment).

*[See here for these examples, and the use of **go** with more prepostions](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go+at)* - The Free Dictionary -